# Facebook api rate limited however headers suggest otherwise

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to use the Instagram graph api to create a post on Instagram programmatically. However, I have recently been getting this error:

{'error': {'message': 'Application request limit reached', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'is_transient': False, 'code': 4, 'error_subcode': 2207051, 'error_user_title': 'action is blocked', 'error_user_msg': 'We restrict certain activity to protect our community. Tell us if you think we made a mistake.', 'fbtrace_id': 'AGTudtgN-M3M3Pjo7aKA2up'}}.

Here are some of the headers from the response:
{"type":"instagram","call_count":1,"total_cputime":1,"total_time":1,"estimated_time_to_regain_access":0}]} 'WWW-Authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Application request limit reached"'

I have tried to create a support request on facebook's platform, but I get the same error that I have exceeded the rate limits.

When I look at the app dashboard, I am nowhere near reaching the rate limit. I have also tried changing API token, and letting the account idle for multiple hours but to no avail. Any reason for this issue? Could this be a bug on Instagram's end?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: No I haven’t, but I created a big report on facebooks end. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/906211033950909/?join_id=f1a08aee88a6bbe. It doesn’t seem like they will update it though